# Jackson ObjectMapper ignore all properties that has no annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson, mongo-jackson-mapper

My target is is to convert jsonObject to Class. I want to add only fields that are anotated in Class. Example: json object holds 50 fields. Class has 4 fields. I want to map only exact 4 fields without adding 46 addition ignores in class.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John",
  "Address": "Some Address 7009",
}
```

**Class:**

```
public static class User {
    Integer id;
    String name;

    public User (@JsonProperty("id")Integer id, @JsonProperty("name")String name {
            this.id= id;
            this.name= name;
    }
    ....
}
```

User class has no address field. My target is to exclude it, because it has no annotation.

Comment: You need to add @JsonIgnore for remaining properties that you don't want

Comment: Did you read my question?

Comment: It is not possible that way. You can either assign @JsonIgnore on remaining properties or you can do turnaround that you can change json key that is not matching object property, vice-versa whatever is possible.

Comment: You can use filters to ignore specific fields. Take a look at @JsonFilter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Annotate your class with [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html), as following:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User {
    ...
}
```

When [`ignoreUnknown`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown()) is `true`, all properties that are unrecognized (that is, there are no setters or creators that accept them) are ignored without warnings (although handlers for unknown properties, if any, will still be called) without exception.

Comment: It is used when any new property which is not available in class

Comment: TeodorKolev has 40 property in class and 40 keys in json and he wants only 4 properties converted into Java object property. Remaining should be default value like null, 0 or whatever. Providing class level annotation will not solve this issue

Comment: @Naman Your comments are really silly. You should read the question.

Comment: @Naman I told you to read the question. I have typed that I have 4 fields in class

Comment: You might be using old version of library. I am using latest Jackson and I don't need to mention this property manually. BDW good luck you got your answer.

Comment: @Naman At the time of this writing, the most recent version of Jackson is 2.8.3 (have a look [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core)). I've just tested with Jackson 2.8.3 and my solution works like a charm.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin you are right it is always backward compatible but it is not required to add this annotation in latest version. I had also achieved this without using any annotation